# Javascript function won't receive Android-Java value

Tags: java, javascript, android

I can't seem to wrap my mind around getting Android-Java to send values to the Javascript in my webview.  No errors, it just won't work.  My first-run storage test to sharedprefs works fine, only passing the result to Javascript fails.  I have tried other ways to do this and they failed also.  I've spent almost a month on this, and searched on here and read plenty.

Should I use something other than a boolean value?  I assume that when the Javascript gets the result, that it will be in a string format.

There must be something I'm doing wrong.  What do I need to change/add/remove to get it working?

Some of my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="1"
android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

My MainActivity.java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private WebView wView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
wView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wView);
wView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
wView.addJavascriptInterface(new Check(this), "Flex"); // firstRunCheck
wView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

My Check.java file, which stores the boolean value I want, in sharedprefs:

```
public class Check extends MainActivity {
Context rContext;
Check(Context d){
 rContext = d;
}
@JavascriptInterface
public void firstRunCheck(String key){
Boolean firstRunCheck = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("firstRunCheck", true);

if (firstRunCheck) {
showAlert();  // this is a call to the showAlert() method.

getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit() 

.putBoolean("firstRunCheck", false).commit();
return;
}
}
}
```

My Javascript function that should get the Java result:

```
Function FirstRunTest(){
var Result = Flex.firstRunCheck()
TextBox1.value = Result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning void.  You need to change the method definition in your Check.java file to return a value.

try:

```
public boolean firstRunCheck(){
  Boolean firstRunCheck = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("firstRunCheck", true);

  if (firstRunCheck) {
    showAlert();  // this is a call to the showAlert() method.

    getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit() 
    .putBoolean("firstRunCheck", false).commit();
  }

  return firstRunCheck;
}
```

in Javascript, assuming Flex.firstRunCheck returns boolean:

```
Function FirstRunTest(){
  var Result = Flex.firstRunCheck();
  TextBox1.value = if(Result) ? "True" : "False";
}
```

Comment: I'll have to give this a try after I get home.

Comment: bob0the0mighty, thank you for taking the time to help me with this, but unfortunately it didn't fix my problem, something else is wrong.  I did learn from your answer though.  I tried to up-vote your answer but it requires that I have at least a 15 reputation, so my "Thank You Very Much" will have to suffice.  I have decided to attack my problem from another angle.

Comment: That's cool.
I just noticed the return is in the check.  You need to move the return to the base scope of the method to get it to compile I imagine.  
Also, I'm not sure what framework you're using besides the ADK.  That may help get an answer quicker.

Comment: In case someone else should have a similar problem, it appears that human error was the reason why the code would not work.  I had another method named "firstRunCheck" at the bottom of a class, so I didn't see it, and since it was empty/null and wasn't called yet, when the value got to my JavaScript function's textbox, it would show up as UNDEFINED.  I renamed the second firstRunCheck, and commented out the first one, so everything should work fine now.